# how to choose libc6 or libc6-dbg

Tags: c++, c, gcc, libc

Im bug checking a c program and would like to install valgrind, the system then tells me that I should also install libc6 with debug symbols libc6-dbg.

Now my question is, when I in the future compile with gcc, which version of libc will be used?

How do I choose which libc6 I'm compiling against?

I'm not asking how to install this, I'm on ubuntu so apt-get install libc6-dbg will do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`libc6-dbg` is not a separate library from `libc6` — it's the debugging symbols for `libc6`, so that you can get accurate tracebacks within libc.

Comment: Yes I'm avare of what debug symbols is. Thats not the question. The question is, whenever I compile how do I tell what libc to compile against? If I omit -ggdb, will gcc then use the non-dbg libc?

Comment: There's no distinction. `libc6` is the library; `libc6-dbg` is its debug symbols, which will be used by gdb/valgrind if they're installed. `-ggdb` controls whether **your** application is compiled with extra debug information.